# Javascript Select

Tags: javascript, select, drop-down-menu

I am working on a form that has multiple SELECT boxes. When a user selects an option from selectbox1, I need another value of selectbox2 active. Likewise when he selects another value of selectbox2, I need another value of selectbox3 active.

```
Select Region 
    <select name='region'>
        <option value='nw'>North West</option>
        <option value='sw'>South West</option>
        <option value='w'>West</option>
    </select>
<br />
Select Quarter
    <select name='quarter'>
        <option value='bda'>Bamenda</option>
        <option value='man'>Mankon</option>
        <option value='ndop'>Ndop</option>
    </select>
<br />
Select Area
    <select name='area'>
        <option value='ba'>Bambili</option>
        <option value='bi'>Bambui</option>
        <option value='cc'>CCk</option>
    </select>
<br />
```

When a user selects NORTH WEST, let BAMENDA be selected on the next select box.

Comment: Have you tried to write any javascript of your own?

Comment: Couple things; 1. This is a help site. People are here to help. Repeatedly writing "please help" does not get you more help. It may get you even less help in fact. 2. Did you try anything on your own first? 3. Resources: learn HTML & Javascript at http://www.codecademy.com , reference these languages at http://www.w3schools.com

Comment: start here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_select_options.asp with a <script>function()</scipt> in your html

Comment: @hacking diablo is `jquery` option ??

Comment: http://www.librairietoubson.com/myproblem.html

Comment: I have explained it here SIR, please help me, atleast on a start                     http://www.librairietoubson.com/myproblem.html

Answer (score 1):

Add an onchange function to the select in HTML, and the javascript function below.

```js
function updateSelect(id) {
    var index = document.getElementById(id).selectedIndex;
    document.getElementById("region").selectedIndex = index;
    document.getElementById("quarter").selectedIndex = index;
    document.getElementById("area").selectedIndex = index;
}
```

```html
Select Region 
<select name='region' id='region' onchange='updateSelect("region")'>
  <option value='nw'>North West</option>
  <option value='sw'>South West</option>
  <option value='w'>West</option>
</select>
<br />
Select Quarter
<select name='quarter' id='quarter' onchange='updateSelect("quarter")'>
  <option value='bda'>Bamenda</option>
  <option value='man'>Mankon</option>
  <option value='ndop'>Ndop</option>
</select>
<br />
Select Area
<select name='area' id='area' onchange='updateSelect("area")'>
  <option value='ba'>Bambili</option>
  <option value='bi'>Bambui</option>
  <option value='cc'>CCk</option>
</select>
```

Comment: THANKS, IT WORKED, this what exactly what I was in search for. thanks a million

Comment: this is th problem i am hacing SIR http://www.librairietoubson.com/myproblem.html

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should load that metadata from somewhere on demand, but if you are fine with static arrays, I made an example fiddle that will work just fine:

[Cascaded selection example](https://jsfiddle.net/pq7t8ysk/1/)

```js
loadQuarters = function () {
    var selectRegion = document.getElementById("selectRegion");
    var selectedRegionValue = selectRegion.options[selectRegion.selectedIndex].value;
    
    resetSelectQuarter();
    
    var allowedQuarters = quarters[selectedRegionValue];     
    
    allowedQuarters.forEach(function(quarter) {
        var selectQuarter = document.getElementById("selectQuarter");
        var optionQuarter = document.createElement("option");
        optionQuarter.text = quarter.label;
        optionQuarter.value = quarter.value;
        selectQuarter.add(optionQuarter);
    });            
}

loadAreas = function () {
    var selectQuarter = document.getElementById("selectQuarter");
    var selectedQuarterValue = selectQuarter.options[selectQuarter.selectedIndex].value;
    
    resetSelectArea();
    
    var allowedAreas = areas[selectedQuarterValue];     
    
    allowedAreas.forEach(function(area) {
        var selectArea = document.getElementById("selectArea");
        var optionArea = document.createElement("option");
        optionArea.text = area.label;
        optionArea.value = area.value;
        selectArea.add(optionArea);
    });            
}

resetSelectArea = function() {
    var selectArea = document.getElementById("selectArea");
    removeOptions(selectArea);
    var optionArea = document.createElement("option");
    optionArea.text = "Select an area";
    optionArea.value = null;
    selectArea.add(optionArea);
}

resetSelectQuarter = function() {
    var selectQuarter = document.getElementById("selectQuarter");
    removeOptions(selectQuarter);
    var optionQuarter = document.createElement("option");
    optionQuarter.text = "Select a quarter";
    optionQuarter.value = null;
    selectQuarter.add(optionQuarter);
}

removeOptions = function(selectbox) {
    var i;
    for(i=selectbox.options.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        selectbox.remove(i);
    }
}

regions = {
    "nw": {
        value: "nw",
        label: "North West"
    },
    "sw": {
        value: "sw",
        label: "South West"
    },
    "w": {
        value: "w",
        label: "West"
    }
};

quarters = {       
    "nw" : [ 
        {
            value: "bda",
            label: "Bamenda"   
        }   
    ],
    "sw" : [
        {            
            value: "man",
            label: "Mankon"        
        }
    ],
    "w" : [
        {            
            value: "ndop",
            label: "Ndop"        
        }
    ]
};

areas = {        
    "bda" : [ 
        {
            value: "ba",
            label: "Bambili"   
        }   
    ],
    "man" : [
        {            
            value: "bi",
            label: "Bambui"        
        }
    ],
    "ndop" : [
        {            
            value: "cc",
            label: "CCk"        
        }
    ]
};
```

```html
Select Region 
<select name='region' id="selectRegion" onChange="loadQuarters()">
    <option> Select a region </option>
    <option value='nw'>North West</option>
    <option value='sw'>South West</option>
    <option value='w'>West</option>
</select>
<br />

Select Quarter
<select name='quarter' id="selectQuarter" onChange="loadAreas()">
    <option> Select a quarter </option>
</select>
<br />
Select Area
<select name='area' id="selectArea">
    <option> Select an area </option>
</select>
<br />
```

Comment: ok, please can i send you the whole code so that you can understand what i want ?

Comment: The problem you linked in [My Problem](http://www.librairietoubson.com/myproblem.html) is solved in a simple way in the snippet I showed. Just replace the static arrays "regions", "quarters" and "areas" with your actual data.
Sorry such late reply!